# How to convert images to video on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, video

I'm looking for a way to convert a sequence of images to a video. And I also want to add sounds to specific time within the video. How can I do that on iPhone? Is there a library that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 4 there is the AvFoundation Framework that is intended to do exactly this. For example iMovie for iPhone is solely built on top of this framework. I'm pretty sure this is exactly what you were looking for. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html) for more details.